# Converting plain text to json

Tags: javascript, node.js

Novice JS developer here, I'm working on a service that pings IoT devices on a network and returns a boolean value depending on the success of the ping.

It's working great but I'm now trying to retrieve some properties from the same IoT devices using the API from the manufacturer through a get request.

The issue is, the API of the devices can't return the values I need in JSON format and instead returns plain text like this:

```
pan=119.81
tilt=-0.22
zoom=1707
focus=7768
```

I would like to get the data like this instead:

```
{
  "pan": 119.81,
  "tilt": -0.22,
  "zoom": 1707,
  "focus": 7768
}
```

At the moment my code looks like this and I'm looking for a way to add the new functionality within:

```
var ping = require('ping');
var cameras = {
    "device_name": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
   };
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/ping', (req, res) => {
    var camera_names = [];
    var promises = [];
    var response = {};
    // console.log(Object.keys(cameras).length)
    Object.keys(cameras).forEach(function (camera) {
        camera_names.push(camera)
        promises.push(ping.promise.probe(cameras[camera], {
            timeout: 1
        }))
    })
    // console.log(promises.length, camera_names.length)
    Promise.all(promises).then((resolved) => {
        resolved.forEach((promise, index) => {
            response[camera_names[index]] = promise.alive
        })
    }).then(() => {
        res.send(response);
    })
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Ping app listening on port 3000!'));
```

One blocker I'm facing is that I need to get a flat JSON but all the properties I need to retrieve have the same names.

Any kind of advice would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an idea can be to split plain text by line and for each one split by = symbol

- index 0 will contain key
- and index 1 will contain data

don't forget to parseFloat index 1 as it will contain a string representation of your data

To convert as json the result you can use method `JSON.stringify`

```js
const data = 
`pan=119.81
tilt=-0.22
zoom=1707
focus=7768`;

const result = {};
let dataKey;
data.split('\n').forEach(oneLine => {
  dataKey = oneLine.split('=');
  result[dataKey[0]] = parseFloat(dataKey[1]);
});

console.log(result);


console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: looks great. Just convert the object into JSON at the end.

Comment: if he asked for it you can edit and add this line JSON.stringify(result);

Comment: yes thank you for your comment i edit my reply to add the conversion in json of the object at the end